# Lucene updateDocument deletes the document, but the counts keep increasing

Tags: java, lucene

I am using `updateDocument()` method to update my document in the lucene index. Here is how I am doing it.

```
writer.updateDocument(new Term(Constants.DOC_ID_FIELD, doc.get(Constants.DOC_ID_FIELD)), doc);
```

I check my index data with Luke, and find that on second run of the indexing, Luke tells that `Deleted Document - not available`. So basically, the document is marked as deleted, but it still resides in the index.

I don't want to keep these marked deleted documents. Am I doing it wrong?

Also, my understanding was that, when I am updating the document, it deletes the old one and then adds the new one. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from the mailing list.

> > `IndexWriter.updateDocument()` deletes and then adds. So your index will have deleted docs.  Why do you care? They'll go away eventually as segments get merged.
> >
> > If you really do care, see `IndexWriter,forceMergeDeletes()`.  See also
> >     the javadoc for that: This is often a horribly costly operation; rarely is it warranted.

Answer (score 0):

The following should delete the document from index:

```
public static void deleteDocumentsFromIndexUsingTerm(Term term) throws IOException, ParseException {

        System.out.println("Deleting documents with field '" + term.field() + "' with text '" + term.text() + "'");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.getDirectory(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
        IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory);
        indexReader.deleteDocuments(term);
        indexReader.close();

    }
```

Reference: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-delete-a-document-from-a-lucene-index-using-the-value-of-a-field.html

Comment: I can do that. I am already looking for that. My understanding was that, when I am updating the document, it deletes the old one and then adds the new one. Is that not the case?

Comment: Also, your suggestion requires to have an IndexReader opened along with an index writer. I am doing this indexing in batch mode. So it might not be an elegant way wherein I am reading the index as well as updating the same.